# How to compute Knockout foreach with if name is equals to $root.selected

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

I have a radio button initially in the page which is saving selected item details with value as name.

```html
<div data-bind="foreach: {data:customer ,as:'customerData'}, visible: customer().length > 0">
    <label class="btn btn-primary active">
    <input type="radio" name="optionsGroup" data-bind="attr: {value:name}, checked: $root.selected">
    <span data-bind="text: customer.type"></span>
  </label>
  </div>
```

Then in the later page I want to show customer details of the selected item. 
I am trying to do like below but I am not getting the desired results and all the objects in customer gets printed instead of selected one.

```html
<div data-bind="foreach: {data:customer,as:'customerData'}, visible: customer().length > 0">
  <div data-bind:"if:$root.selected() === customer.name">
    <p data-bind="text:customer.name" class="w3-center"></p>
    <p data-bind="text:customer.college" class="w3-center"></p>
    <p data-bind="text:customer.school" class="w3-center"></p>
  </div>
```

I tried to make a foreach with if condition but that does'nt solve the problem as i stated earlier in the post also the json file looks like this:

```html
"customer": [{
            "order": "01",
            "name": "custom 1",
            "type": "A1",
            "school": "ABCDS",
            "College": "university of florida"
             },
              {
             "order": "02",
            "name": "custom 2",
            "type": "A2",
            "school": "ABCDS",
            "College": "university of new york"
             }
     ]
```

Comment: Is "customer" an array or a single item? Your code is treating it as both. I think you mean to bind your texts to "customerData" not "customer"

Comment: My customer is Array of objects. I want to bind the text with customerData but only when a specific customer is chosen. Like if customer 2 is chosen , so text with be shown of customer 2 only not of all the customers

Comment: I think @JasonSpake meant to say you'll have to bind to: `if:$root.selected() === customerData.name`

Comment: does if work under foreach to work as a where clause in for loop                          like for(i=0;i<n;i++)